# Displaying an image in php from a file in a directory

Tags: php, html, image, mime-types, imagesource

I have several images in a directory which is located outside of the public facing portion of the server (outside of the public_html directory). I want to be able to read the image contents with a php file, then output the result to html.

For example, I have a php file called getimg.php with the following source code:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$dir = '/home/server/images/';
$file_name = addslashes($_GET['file']);

readfile('' . $dir . '' . $file_name . '.jpg');
```

getimg.php reads the contents of a jpg image in the images directory, then is referenced using the following code when I want to display the image to a user:

```
<img src="getimg.php?file=name_of_image_file">
```

The getimg.php file also does some verification checks to ensure that the user is logged in, actually owns the image they are trying to view, etc (this is not shown above for simplicity's sake). This approach is meant to control access to the image files. However, that is not the matter at hand.

Here is the problem: The approach/code above is only working in the Chrome browser. The images are not properly displaying in IE, FF, Safari, or Opera. Any ideas why this isn't working or how to do this properly?

**Notes:**

- I am trying to avoid using mysql to
  store the images due to the large
  quantity of images. Being able to utilize the filesystem is greatly preferable here.
- The solution must be cross browser
  friendly.
- In reality, the image can be a jpg,
  png, or gif file. For the sake of
  simplicity, the above code only
  handles jpg images.
- I doubt it is relevant, but **I am
  NOT using jQuery. And no, I will not
  alter my entire site to use jQuery. Any "use jQuery" posts will automatically receive a downvote**. I don't hate jquery.. it's just not the right solution for my site.

**UPDATE**

The problem was not with the code itself. I had my php.ini file set to auto include a login verification script. Since I was not logged in all of my browsers, the image was not displaying. Silly mistake, but understandable and fixed. The code above should work just fine. It has also been updated to use readfile() instead of file_get_contents(). I am going to leave this post up for anyone that's browsing the web looking for a way to control who has access to an image using php.

Comment: How exactly is the image "not properly displaying" in IE/FF? Exactly what happens? We can't help you unless you tell us what's happening.

Comment: `addslashes()` doesn't belong there. It could mess up the filename, which could contribute to your problems. You should use `basename()` and maybe some ctype functions to sanitize filenames. Also, `file_get_contents()` can cause you to run out of memory if the file is big. Drop the echo and use `readfile()` instead.

Comment: Sorry about that, I improperly assumed clarity on that part. In the <img src="getimg.php?file=name_of_image_file"> part, the output shows up as if I entered the wrong url. In other words, it's like I set the src to a jpg file that does not exist and it shows up as a broken image.

Comment: for some strange reason your code is working on my local, check your $dir variable, im sure that's where your error resides

Comment: jquery is useless in this situation, don't know why you think youd get that as an answer.

Comment: addslashes() is just something I used here as an example. In the real example, the security measures are far more extensive. The filenames are strictly alphanumeric so I pass it through a more rigorous, robust filter. The image files are controlled in size (no more than 80 kilobytes) so unpredictable filesizes aren't an issue. However, I will use readfile nonetheless.

Comment: Another thing to check is your error logs. Possible your server doesn't have permission to access files outside of the web root directory.

Comment: Galen, I said that only because every time I post something that I think has nothing to do with jQuery, I always end up getting one jQuery post. Apparently, it has a cross browser function to create world peace and make sandwiches. 

Mark, I checked the error logs. The permissions are working properly. For the sake of reducing points of error, I am using a directory in the public portion of the server to host the images. I will move it to the "hidden" directory after I get this worked out.

Comment: what is the output when you type: getimg.php?file=name_of_image_file in your browser?

Comment: Ah, I figured out what was wrong. I made a very, very stupid mistake. I had my php.ini file set to auto include a login verification file in the header. I was logged in on my chrome browser so the image was displaying. I was logged out in the rest of my browsers so it was not displaying. At least I know the security system works.

Comment: I had to give you +1 for "it has a cross browser function to create world peace and make sandwiches".

Answer (score 3):

Use the readfile function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: Probably not related to the specific issue, but this is definitely the correct function to use for this

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
if($fileExt == 'jpg'){
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filePath);
    if ($im !== false) {
       header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
       imagejpeg($im);
    }
}
if($fileExt == 'png'){
$im = imagecreatefrompng($filePath);
    if ($im !== false) {
       header('Content-Type: image/png');
       imagepng($im);
    }
}
```

if the image is gif, there is also imagecreatefromgif()

Answer (score 0):

I've used the approach you've outlined previously and it does work. The fact that it works in Chrome suggests it's a browser issue. Three suggestions:

1. Use the Firefox Live Headers extension or `curl -I` to see exactly what headers PHP is sending when getimg.php is requested. There could a Content-Encoding or gzip compression issue. You may also want to send headers such that the browser caches the image - by default PHP will send headers to prevent this.
2. Use a RewriteRule so that you can use src="file_name.jpg" ie.

   RewriteRule ^(.+).jpg$     getimage.php?file=$1.jpg
3. Use jQuery. jQuery always works.